# Installing Oracle Instant Client

Tags: oracle, installation

I can't seem to figure out how to install the Oracle client on Windows Server 2008.

I downloaded [x64 version (the first file on the list) here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html). There are installation instructions on the bottom of that page:

Step 2 ("instantclient")

Which executable should I run?

Comment: You need to unzip it. Did you find setup.exe in it?

Comment: i unziped, but there is no setup.exe. i only see the following application files: adrci, genezi and uidrvci

Comment: when i click on them, i keep getting "invalid windows applicaton" error

Comment: For sanity, are you trying to install the full Oracle client (what you would install if you wanted to run a GUI like TOAD)?  Or are you trying to install the Oracle Instant Client-- a very stripped-down version of the client that is intended to be bundled and installed with an application that you write and install?  It sounds like you have downloaded the Instant Client but if you're looking for an installer, you'd want the full client.

Comment: I'm looking for something that will allow me to connect to our Oracle, so i can migrate data over...

Comment: @xrum - What application(s) are you using to migrate data?  Is this an application you've written?  Or a commercial app?

Comment: i am going to use SQL Server Management Studio to create a SSIS package, to then schedule to run nightly.. it will (or at least should) move data from oracle to sql nightly... but right now there is no Oracle in the SQL Server MS import data source - drop down. so i thought i had to install Oracle client, to get all proper drivers and things show up.

Comment: FYI- Just because you have 64 bit platform does not mean you wan the 64bit client.    The application determines the version of the client it needs.   A 32bit application needs the 32bit client, a 64bit app needs the 64 bit Client.

Answer (score 43):

The instantclient works **only** by defining the folder in the windows PATH environment variable. **But you can "install" manually** to create some keys in the Windows registry. **How?**

**1)** Download instantclient (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)

**2)** Unzip the ZIP file (eg c:\oracle\instantclient).

**3)** Include the above path in the PATH.
[image: Set PATH in Windows]

**4)** Create the registry key:

- Windows 32bit: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE]`
- Windows 64bit: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE]`

**5)** In the above registry key, create a sub-key starts with "KEY_" followed by the name of the installation you want:

- Windows 32bit: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_INSTANTCLIENT]`
- Windows 64bit: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_INSTANTCLIENT]`

**6)** Now create at least three string values ​​in the above key:

- `NLS_LANG = BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.WE8MSWIN1252` *(complete list here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14317/gblsupp.htm)*
- `ORACLE_HOME = c:\oracle\instantclient` *(the same folder in PATH)*
- `ORACLE_HOME_NAME = MY_INSTANTCLIENT` *(choose any name)*

[image: registry keys for Oracle Home]

For those who use Quest SQL Navigator or **Quest Toad for Oracle** will see that it works. Displays the message "Home is valid.":

[image: Displays the message "Home is valid." in Quest Toad (or SQL Navigator)]

The registry keys are now displayed for selecting the oracle client:

[image: selecting the oracle client in Quest SQL Navigator]

Comment: Does Oracle know what "instant" means?

Comment: @AaronLS It's pretty "instant" compared with the full Oracle installer

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for establishing ODBC connections for the instant client.

Comment: OK, in Windows, to establish ODBC connections using Oracle Instant Client, you must download three things: 1) the basic instant client package, 2) the accompanying ODBC package, and 3) the requisite Visual Studio redistributable.  Install the VS redistributable, unzip all the oracle instant client files into a single directory, and run the odbc_install.exe.  Now, when you invoke the ODBC setup dialog, Oracle Instant Client should be an option.  (Still checking if I need to set up a tnsnames.ora file...)

Comment: Such a 1980 way to install things. Congrats Oracle!!

Answer (score 18):

I was able to setup Oracle Instant Client (Basic) 11g2 and Oracle ODBC (32bit) drivers on my 32bit Windows 7 PC.  Note: you'll need a 'tnsnames.ora' file because it doesn't come with one.  You can Google examples and copy/paste into a text file, change the parameters for your environment.

**Setting up Oracle Instant Client-Basic 11g2 (Win7 32-bit)**
(I think there's another step or two if your using 64-bit)

**Oracle Instant Client**

- Unzip Oracle Instant Client - Basic
- Put contents in folder like "C:\instantclient"
- Edit PATH evironment variable, add path to Instant Client folder to the Variable Value.
- Add new Variable called "TNS_ADMIN"  point to same folder as Instant Client.
- I had to create a "tnsnames.ora" file because it doesn't come with one.  Put it in same folder as the client.
- reboot or use Task Manager to kill "explorer.exe" and restart it to refresh the PATH environment variables.

**ODBC Drivers**

- Unzip ODBC drivers
- Copy all files into same folder as client "C:\instantclient"
- Use command prompt to run "odbc_install.exe" (should say it was successful)

Note:  The "un-documented" things that were hanging me up where...
 - All files (Client and Drivers) needed to be in the same folder (nothing in sub-folders).
 - Running the ODBC driver from the command prompt will allow you to see if it installs successfully. Double-clicking the installer just flashed a box on the screen, no idea it was failing because no error dialog.

After you've done this you should be able to setup a new DSN Data Source using the Oracle ODBC driver.
-Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: ODBC drivers is what I needed to get my Visual Studio project talking to oracle with the managed driver.

Comment: This worked for me when I got "You have no Oracle clients installed" and "You do not have any Oracle homes installed" after installing TOAD and pointing it to the instant client zip.

Answer (score 9):

The directions state:

> 1. Download the appropriate Instant Client packages for your platform. All installations REQUIRE the Basic package.
> 2. Unzip the packages into a single directory such as "instantclient".
> 3. Set the library loading path in your environment to the directory in Step 2 ("instantclient"). On many UNIX platforms, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the appropriate environment variable. On Windows, PATH should be used.
> 4. Start your application and enjoy.

Suggest extracting/unzipping into a new directory. They've *suggested* `instantclient`, but you can name the directory anything you like. Name it `C:\OracleInstantClient\` if you choose.

Then in Step 3, open a Windows Command Prompt. Type:

```
PATH C:\OracleInstantClient; %PATH%`
```

That's all there is to it!

Comment: @xrum: nothing's supposed to happen, really. Please see the updated syntax.

Comment: per comments above. am i even installing the right thing? i thought i needed to download instant client, to be able to connect to our oracle server...

Comment: It's unclear whether you're running the right thing. What exactly are your requirements? A 'SQL Server Management Studio'-like program? A command line client?

Comment: I need to migrate data from SQL to ORacle, but i was told that i need to install ORACLE client on the machine first, to be able to set up the ODBC connection. so confused :( but i guess i am looking for a SQL Server Management Studio like program.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use SQL Server Management Studio, you want to install the full Oracle client, not the Instant Client.  The full Oracle client is on the [same download page as the Oracle database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html).  Assuming that you are installing on a 64-bit version of Windows, I expect you want the "Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64)" download.  This is several hundred MB rather than a couple of MB for the Instant Client.

Answer (score 1):

Try SQLDeveloper - there is a migration workbench there

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html