# SSMA for Oracle "Connect to Oracle" error

Tags: oracle, odac, dbconnection, sql-server-migration-assi

i tried to connect to Oracle using Sql server migration assistant for oracle(SSMA for oracle).
and specified parameters like this

provider: **Oracle Client Provider**

mode: standard mode

and connection info(servername, port ...)

but i got a error message

> "Unable to find specified provider.
>   Compatible Oracle Data Access Connectivity libraries were not found on the machine. You can install them from Oracle product media or download it from Oracle web site."

so i installed `Oracle Data Access Components`(ODAC), 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

but same error message appeared.

what is Compatible Oracle Data Access Connectivity library?

Comment: Is it 32 of 64 bit drivers?

Comment: it is 64bit driver

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) are required for applications to connect to the database, to use "SSMA" you need to install Oracle instant client,

1) Download http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html

2) Unzip, then add the folder to the path, open control panel > system > Advanced > Environment Vriables > choose Path and Edit it to add a new entry with your folder.

3) Connect with the 'system' user (user id = system)

see also this answer it helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/26439785/4542599