# Unable to connect to Oracle using SSMA for Oracle

Tags: oracle, azure-sql-database

I'm trying use Microsoft SSMA for Oracle to migrate a database onto Azure SQL, but I can't get it going. I've double checked the server name, server port, Oracle SID, password... everything. No matter the type of entry screen I use, I can't get it to connect to the on-premise Oracle instance.

I'm pretty sure the login information is all correct, and I should have a working connector to Oracle since I connect to it from TOAD on a daily basis. I tried installing Oracle libraries per [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006803/ssma-for-oracle-connect-to-oracle-error) but not sure if I did it successfully because the issues still remains.
 What are the troubleshooting steps I should take in order to make this work?

Log in screen:
      [image]

Error 1:

> Unable to find specified provider.
>   Compatible Oracle Data Access Connectivity libraries were not found on the machine.  You can install them from Oracle product media or download it from Oracle web site.

Error 2:

> Connection to Oracle failed.
>   ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Error 3:

> Connection to Oracle failed.
>   Network Naming: No LDAP server detected or configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more days of debugging, I was finally able to get SSMA to work. This answer helps to document my solution for personal use, as well as hopefully answer anyone else's question in the future.

1. After looking at the [list of prerequisites to have SSMA running](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/installing-ssma-for-oracle-client-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017#prerequisites), I saw that I needed to have a correct Oracle client running. After some internal discussion, it was likely that the Oracle client SSMA needed was different than the one my computer already had for TOAD. The .Net provider for the TOAD connectors was probably not useful for SSMA.
2. We run Oracle 11g but I had to install Oracle 12c because [11g did not support Windows 10 apparently](https://kb.iu.edu/d/azoc). Not too much of a roadblock here.
3. I found [this guide to install Oracle client 12c pretty helpful.](https://www.aits.uillinois.edu/UserFiles/Servers/Server_474/File/DS/ODBC/How%20To%20Install%20Oracle%2012c%20client.pdf) Shoutout to my alma mater.
4. Unfortunately the installer kept freezer, but [using this former post](https://serverfault.com/questions/919519/windows-10-installing-oracle-client-12c-or-18c-hanging-at-step1), I was able to bypass it with the windows command:

`setup.exe  -ignoreprereq -J"-Doracle.install.client.validate.clientSupportedOSCheck=false"`

5. After that, I saw different error messages when trying to connect SSMA. I kept trying different options with my logins until it worked. Provider: OLEDB Provider, Mode: Standard.
6. After being granted [the appropriate permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/connecting-to-oracle-database-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017#required-oracle-permissions), I was finally able to access our internal tables and objects.

It was a pretty annoying question with a lot of rabbit holes along the way, but it was definitely worth it, being able to translate all our Oracle schemas to Azure SQL with a few clicks. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to validate all steps mentioned below before going to install Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle.

- Make sure you have already installed SQL Server instance that will    host the migrated database. Also keep in mind that you are not    installing SQL Server Express edition to host the migrated database.
- You must have sysadmin account to install SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle.
- Make sure to install SSMA for Oracle on the server that will host newly migrated database on SQL Server.
- It is recommended to install Oracle client software on your target system    where SQL Server Instance is running.
- Make sure your windows server has Microsoft Windows Installer 3.1 or a later version. Port 1434 should be open.

For more details, You can reference: [How to Install SSMA for Oracle to Migrate Oracle Database to SQL Server](https://techyaz.com/sql-server/migrations/how-to-install-ssma-for-oracle-to-migrate-oracle-database-to-sql-server/).

Here's the Azure Database Migration Guide: [Migrate Oracle to Azure SQL Database](https://datamigration.microsoft.com/scenario/oracle-to-azuresqldb?step=1). As you prepare for migrating to the cloud, verify that your source environment is supported and that you have addressed any prerequisites. This will help to ensure an efficient and successful migration.

Connect to Oracle with `Oracle Client Provider`.
[image]

Azure also has other way can help you migrate Oracle database to Azure SQL database, such as with Azure Data Factory. If you still has the connect error. I think you can try to use it. Please reference this tutorial: [Copy data from and to Oracle by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it appears that I missed a lot of the setup/verification steps for using SSMA. There's too much Github information that's too technical for me so I'll first try the Data Factory method. Thanks for this!

Comment: You're welcome,@Yaga. I'm  glad that my answer can helps you.  Hope you can accept it, thanks and have a good day.