# Django - ERROR: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: python, django, oracle12c

I am using an Oracle db backend in my django project. I am able to connect to my remote Oracle db using sqlplus from the CMD line and using an Oracle SQL developer. Whenever I try to use `python manage.py dbshell` it returns the oracle error.

```
SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\dbshell.py", line 22, in handle
    connection.client.runshell()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\client.py", line 12, in runshell
    subprocess.check_call(args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 341, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['sqlplus', '-L', 'system/\\"password\\"@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=8080))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=temp)))']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

### Settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'temp',
        'USER': 'system',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': '8080',
    }
}
```

I modified the DB information for security purposes but the settings.py information should match the stack trace error.

Any suggestions as to what I should try or maybe I am forgetting to set something?

Comment: Where is the database running? It sounds like a simple case of the settings being wrong & django can't connect to `host` on port 8080. Consider that port 8080 would usually be an HTTP port, not a database port.

Comment: Database is running on a server on a shared network. I created the django project on my local machine and want to use the oracle db as the backend. Also, I can see how the 8080 can be confusing, that port number was meant to substitute my actual port number for security reasons

Comment: Not related to your error but you should never ever configure an application to use the `sys` or `system` database users.  That will create a number of problems for you down the line.

Comment: @justincave Im aware, I was receiving the same error using my actual DB user so I decided to try the sys user to see if I would have the problem which I did, Its strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to fix it in Django, but the problem seems to be the way the password is being escaped. You can test this by using the `sqlplus` command directly based on the failed subprocess output.

This fails:

```
# From error: [sqlplus', '-L', 'user/\\"password\\"@some_dsn
sqlplus -L user/\\"password\\"@some_dsn
```

This works:

```
sqlplus -L user/password@some_dsn
```

Might explore submitting a patch for oracle/sqlplus in Django, but I don't see this working any time soon. You can wiggle all the Django knobs, I think this is a low-level issue you won't fix by adjusting your settings.

Answer (score 0):

try this configuration or you can read this part of django.  [db_oracle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#id11).

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': 'temp',
    'USER': 'password',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that due to reading the documentation through the django website. It returns the same Oracle error saying invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: With the empty fields?

Comment: Yes, omitting the host and port just as you and the documentation had done. I am also using a tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: check this. https://community.oracle.com/thread/4033830 || https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809195/installing-oracle-instant-client

Comment: I dont believe the issue is being caused from the Oracle client being installed incorrectly being that I can access my remote DB through the CMD line using the same User and Password. The problem has to lie on Djangos end.